# Management software to organize ISO Images

Tags: file-management, iso

I am searching for management software to organize ISO images, like Calibre for E-Books.

**Information:**

- Manufacturer
- Version
- Manufacturer's website

**Optional functions:**

- Web server for external Hosting
- Access permissions for web server

I hope there is such a software for my purposes. Preferred OS is Windows, but Unix is not a problem. I hope that I don't need to pay for a solution, but recommendations are open and I would look if it is too much or not.

Answer (score 1):

CD Archiver has similar functionality and supports ISO.
http://pmcchp.com/cdarchiver/index.html
(Moderator's note: Site down as of 2021 May.)

If site is still down, see alternatives at: https://alternativeto.net/software/cd-archiver